# Error on my laptop"BOOTMGR is missing"

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios, bootmgr

some error display on my laptop
"BOOTMGR is missing
 press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart"
And one more problem my laptop not dected usb drive in BIOS.

Comment: It is nearly impossible to help you with that information. Describe what have you done before that happened, what did you try, what is your BIOS etc.

Comment: my BIOS version is 4FCNA1WW (lenovo b460e)..

Comment: sir ,this is not possible ah?

Comment: `then how will do?` This is not a question which can expect not only good answers, but any answers at all. Please edit your question and read http://superuser.com/help

Comment: Kind of sounds like there are two separate problems. You tried to turn on and boot the laptop and it told you _BOOTMGR is missing_, correct? You then tried to boot it off a USB drive and you expect the USB device to show in the PATA/SATA hard drive settings, which it won't, correct? BIOS version is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

> BOOTMGR is missing press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

Something has messed up the ability to boot off your primary hard drive. You will need to create a **System Recovery Disk** on another Windows 7 system as this one is currently not bootable. Control Panel -> Backup and Restore -> Create a System Repair Disk, have a blank CD ready to burn.

1. Remove all USB devices plugged into the machine except keyboard and mouse (laptop so not applicable).
2. Check your BIOS settings for your hard drives. BIOS should recognize the internal hard drive and list it. If not, you have a cable loose or the hard drive has failed.
3. Check your BIOS settings for boot device priority. Make sure it shows the DVD drive and the hard drive at a bare minimum and that the DVD drive is listed as the first item, followed by the hard drive.
4. Insert your Windows 7 System Recovery disk in the DVD drive and boot into **System Recovery** (Repair your computer) and select the **Startup Repair** option. Try rebooting.
5. If that didn't do the job, reboot off the Windows 7 install disk into **System Recovery** and this time, select the **Command Prompt** option. From the command prompt, run `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` followed by `bootrec.exe /fixboot`. See if the computer will boot.

[Use the Bootrec.exe tool in the Windows Recovery Environment to troubleshoot and repair startup issues in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392)

And for your information, USB based devices are removable and will not be showing in your BIOS. You can enable booting off them in the BIOS but they're peripherals, not internal devices.